# VIN Programming for new ECU on 2010 Jeep Wrangler 3.8l w/ Manual Transmission

Tags: jeep, electronic-control-module, chrysler, reprogram, flash-programing

I've run into an issue with a 2010 Jeep Wrangler.

We've recently replace the ECU with a brand new one from the dealer and unfortunately, it was not pre-programmed for the vehicles VIN. All local mobile programmers are either too busy or have not responded and I am starting to wonder if there's a reason for this.

Snapon scan tool was unable to write VIN to ECU, but have been researching other methods to do so without spending thousands on new equipment that will only be used once. After researching a little with little success, I have come across the ISO 15765-4 HSCAN protocol as the implemented protocol for this model jeep, can anybody concur?

Basically, I am wondering if anybody has had success with writing VIN to Jeep's ECUs for the models after 2008 using either Snapon scantool or HSCAN DLC to USB connection, possibly using the ELM327 IC-based connection or must we submit to Chrysler's proprietary headache and send the vehicle to the dealership to be initialized?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

None of the methods you are suggesting (Snap-On, HSCAN, ELM327) are going to work. The reason is, everything you've mentioned has to do with *scanning* the ECU. You need software/hardware which can *write* to the ECU. Most people in the automotive world call this *tuning*. While you don't need your ECU tuned, to get the VIN into it requires the same type of procedure.

Just reading through a few things, it appears if you bought this from Jeep, it may not have *any* programming on it. If so, this would most likely require it to go to a dealership which would have the ability to write the required software to it. In order for a "tuner" to put the VIN onto the ECU, they must first pull what software is on there off of it (copy it to their computer). Then they make the VIN changes and write it back to the ECU. If your ECU has never been flashed in the first place, there's nothing to pull off to make changes to. If you can find someone with a base tune for your vehicle, or if the original ECU can be read by a tuner, then they may be able to pull the original tune off of it and place it onto your new ECU. Chances are if you're having problems getting anyone to do the tuning for you now you aren't going to find anyone who has what is needed to get it setup properly. Your best bet is to take it to a dealership.

As an aside, it can be read and modified by tuners. Since I'm familiar with HPTuners (no affiliation), I can tell you using their hardware/software it can be done. If at least one such entity exists then you can bet there are others. You just have to find the right one.